# Contar saída de produto no dia em mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela de saida de materiais de estoque que está organizada da seguinte maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho produtos em estoque a toda vez que sair é lançado o numero indicando o id do produto, a quantidade de saída e o dia, ao longo do dia pode haver vários registros de saídas do mesmo produto.

Eu preciso pegar os valores de saída de determinado produto em determinado dia e somar para saber quantos produtos saíram no dia especificado, estou tentando a seguindo query

```
SELECT COUNT(qtd_saida) as total FROM tbl_limpeza_saida_diaria WHERE produto_id=7 AND data_uso=DATE(NOW())
```

Porém desta forma acima me trás a quantidade de registros e não a soma de saídas do produto.

Como faço para somar a quantidade de saída de determinado produto em determinado dia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse DBAlone:

```
SELECT produto_id, data_uso, SUM(qtd_saida) as total FROM tbl_limpeza_saida_diaria 
WHERE produto_id=7 AND data_uso=DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY produto_id, data_uso;
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: Se serviu marque a resposta como como certa

Answer (score -2):

Tente com um `groupBy` por data, forçando o `ID` do produto e juntando eles pela data e somando a `Qtde`